# How to deliver javascript code using Springboot

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to implement a requirement, where I need to deliver javascript code securely. My Idea is,
I will make the path as /something.js and in the controller, I will check the authentication, if not authenticate I will deliver console.error("Auth Failed").

How I can achieve the above scenario.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'deliver JS code securely'? If you're attempting to make the content of the JS scripts which run on the page inaccessible, then that's not really possible. Obfuscation is about as good as you can get.

Comment: It's simplest to just define a directory for scripts (like `/js`) and in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` make that directory accessible only to authenticated users.  There won't be a printout to the console, but anyone using developer tools will be able to see that the script got a 403 or 404 error.  It will be invisible to regular users.

Comment: Of course, it would be better to design publicly-accessible pages to use publicly-accessible script and CSS files, and authenticated-user-only pages to use authenticated-user-only scripts and CSS...

Comment: I think @workerjoe I can configure that in websecurityadapter. Delver Js means a link or a route which will return javascript code, but that javascript code will not be the physical path, The controller will check the authentication some way, that I can do. and allow the javascript (string) to return or not.

Comment: @SubhenduMondal So, you want to prevent a 403 or 404 error?  Well, then just define an endpont as a `@GetMapping` and incorporate an `if/then` statement.  If authenticated, return one javascript file, else, return another javascript file (one that does nothing except deliver the `console.error()` you want.

Comment: @workerjoe Yes, you right. I achieve by adding a Filter to check. In that case, I write the response if unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

this is the simplest way using common request handler. works 100 %

```
@GetMapping(value = "/hello.js") 
public void resources( HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws Exception {
    //Authentication goes here or using handler interceptor
    httpResponse.setContentType("text/javascript");
    httpResponse.setHeader("MIME-type", "text/javascript");
    httpResponse.getWriter().write(" function alertMan(msg) { \n alert(\"message:\"+msg); \n } ");
}
```